# Get the count of a phrase in a url using python and bs4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the count of any phrase appearing in a URL, say `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
```

Now, I want to get the count of the phrase `India is a` in the soup. How to go about this?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one of two ways.

First, the common denominator:

```
texts = soup.find_all(text=True)
cleaned = ["".join(t.strip()) for t in texts]
counter=0
```

Now, if you want to use regex:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\bIndia is a\b') 
for c in cleaned:
    if regex.match(c) is not None:
        counter+=1
```

I, personally, don't like using regex except as last resort, so I would go the longer way

```
phrase = 'India is a'
for c in cleaned:   
            if phrase==c or phrase+' ' in c: 
                counter+=1
```

In both cases, `print(counter)` outputs `6`.

Note that, intentionally, these do not count the 3 situations where the phrase is part of a larger phrase (such as `India is also`); it counts only the exact phrase or the phrase followed by a space.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below and the same worked fine:

```
import re
import requests
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India'

response = requests.get(url)
response_text = response.text
keyword = 'India is a'

match = re.findall("%s" % keyword, response_text)
count = (len(match))
count
```

Output is `9`.

This code will look into `<head>`, `<body>` and elsewhere.